# How to run raw query in ElasticSearch 6.5.1 using JavaHighLevelRestClient?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to run a raw query on elastic search version 6.5.1 using JavaHighLevelRestClient

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "Neeraj"
    }
  }
}
```

In the previous versions of elastic with **PreBuiltTransportClient**, we can achieve it using

```
SearchResponce searchResponse = client.prepareSearch()
.setQuery("{ "query": { "match": { "name": "Neeraj" } } }").get();
```

And [RestHighLevelClient](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client/6.6.2/index.html) doesn't have any such method `prepareSearch` so
how we can achieve the same with **RestHighLevelClient** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution in [Elastic Docs](https://www.elastic.co/search?fv-website_area=documentation&fv-product_name=Elasticsearch&fv-product_version=6.7&q=simpleQueryStringQuery&size=20) to achieve this, we can use **QueryBuilders's** `simpleQueryStringQuery` method to achieve this :

```
 String query = "{ \"query\": { \"match\": { \"name\": \"Neeraj\" } } }";

 SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
 searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.simpleQueryStringQuery(query));
 searchSourceBuilder.from(0);
 searchSourceBuilder.size(10);

 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
 searchRequest.indices(indexName);
 searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);


 SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
 List<MyRecordDTO> goldenRecords = getSearchResult(searchResponse);
```

As per documentation

> ```
> /**
>  * A query that acts similar to a query_string query, but won't throw
>  * exceptions for any weird string syntax. See
>  * {@link org.apache.lucene.queryparser.simple.SimpleQueryParser} for the full
>  * supported syntax.
>  */
> public static SimpleQueryStringBuilder simpleQueryStringQuery(String queryString) {
>     return new SimpleQueryStringBuilder(queryString);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

documentation is really nice and contains many example:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-search.html

In your case this should be:

```
   SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("my_index");
    val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder;
    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("name", "Neeraj");
    searchSourceBuilder.query(query)
    searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)
    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

Note you could write the request on a single line too.

Comment: I just gave a simple example, my actual query is much more complex and I don't want to programmatically construct it instead, provide the actual query and directly run it as shown in the description of my question. I know I can use QueryBuilders tio build queries but I don't want to use it.

Comment: You mean you want to send a json?

Comment: `SearchResponce searchResponse = client.prepareSearch()
.setQuery("{ "query": { "match": { "name": "Neeraj" } } }").get();` I am looking for a similar example in HighLevelRestClient, this example works perfectly fine with the previous version of RestClient but not with HighLevelRestClient.